# Trying to read HtmlElement from ccd.xml using java

Tags: java, html, xml, ccd

I am parsing ccd.xml using java.
Each node/element of ccd I can access using java object.

Query: while htmlElement come in any node of ccd. my java object does not reach to that node?
I can get templateId, title but after reaching text node of ccd.xml, my java object not able to show table node.

Sample ccd.xml shown below:

```
<component>
<section>
    <templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.9'/> <!-- Payers section template -->
    <code code="48768-6" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1"/>
    <title>Payers</title>
    <text>
        <table border="1" width="100%">
            <thead>
            <tr><th>Payer name</th><th>Policy type / Coverage type</th><th>Covered party ID</th> <th>Authorization(s)</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Good Health Insurance</td> 
                    <td>Extended healthcare / Self</td> 
                    <td>14d4a520-7aae-11db-9fe1-0800200c9a66</td>
                    <td>Colonoscopy</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </text>

</section>
</component>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at MDHT - an open source project to read/write CDA Content
The Text Attribute is a mixed content
 https://www.projects.openhealthtools.org/sf/projects/mdht/

Comment: I studied openhealthtools, is there any lib. to read <text><table></table><text> node, because while I try this Component3 t= ccdDocument.getComponent().getStructuredBody().getComponents().get(0);   Object s = t.getSection().getText().getMixed().get(0).getValue();  System.out.println(s);  I am getting Blank output on console